# Backbone.js Model does not inherit from collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model, requirejs

I have a model called `score` and a collection called `scores`. However, the model does not seem to be inheriting the `localStorage` property (or for that matter, any property) from the parent collection. Am I missing something here?

Running Backbone with RequireJS.

**models/score.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'localstorage'
], function(_, Backbone, Store){
    var ScoreModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            board_id: null,
            ns_pair: null,
            ew_pair: null,
            ns_score: null
        },
        validate: function(attrs, options){
            if( isNaN(attrs.board_id) || attrs.board_id < 1 ){
                return 'Invalid Board ID!';
            }
        },
        localStorage: new Store("ScoreCollection")
    });
    return ScoreModel;
});
```

**collections/scores.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/score',
    'localstorage'
], function(_, Backbone, ScoreModel, Store){
    var ScoreCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScoreModel,
        localStorage: new Store("ScoreCollection")
    });
    return ScoreCollection;
});
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    // Major libraries
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore.min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone.min',

    // Require.js plugins
    text: 'libs/require/text',

    // Backbone.js plugins
    localstorage: 'libs/backbone/localstorage',

    // Just a short cut so we can put our html outside the js dir
    // When you have HTML/CSS designers this aids in keeping them out of the js directory
    templates: '../templates'
  }
});

// Let's kick off the application

require([
  'app'
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

Comment: I don't see your data inheriting something else besides Backbone.Collection and Backbone.Model. Also I think that you don't need to declare a localStorage on your Model.

Comment: @svetoslavnedkov The problem is that localStorage doesn't work IF I don't declare it in my model. It should, but it's not.

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone Models don't inherit from Backbone Collections. They're just extensions of the base Backbone.Model that you 'extend' with your own properties and methods. Collections, the same deal. You can specify that a collection's model is based on a particular model you've defined so that when collections are added to it, it uses the model constructor to create instances for each model in that collection, but there is no direct inheritance relationship there. You can define a property on a model that happens to be an instance of a collection if that suits your needs.